# Bitconnect transactions show in block explorer, but one transaction is missing from wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet, altcoin, bitconnect-coin

My Bitconnect address `8Y7D6YfD7htnQ7uYaDHZzQSHtjiXRZfsZ9` has received 2 transactions according to [this Bitconnect block explorer tool](https://chainz.cryptoid.info/bcc/address.dws?8Y7D6YfD7htnQ7uYaDHZzQSHtjiXRZfsZ9.htm) but only the smaller one for 0.01 is showing up in my Bitconnect wallet client. The other transaction for 3.44479734BCC shows around 6000 confirmations in the block explorer, but hasn't appeared in my wallet.

Why is this transaction not showing up, or at least, what I can do about it?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Which wallet are you using to look for it? What is the transaction id? What were you expecting to see?

Comment: I am using a coin specific wallet. it's the bitconnect wallet https://chainz.cryptoid.info/bcc/address.dws?8Y7D6YfD7htnQ7uYaDHZzQSHtjiXRZfsZ9.htm this is the wallet the 0.001 BCC came but the 3.4 didnt come :(

Comment: I've rewritten the question. I hope that helps others to understand the issue and assist you...

Comment: so you can nt help?

Comment: I probably can't help any further, though others on the site may be able to. In the meantime, I suggest trying to contact someone who knows more about how the Bitconnect wallet works, through perhaps reddit or bitcointalk (in an appropriate subreddit or thread). I've helped you clarify your question so that others will be able to better understand the issue, so you could copy and paste it.